# Startforeground being killed

Tags: android, android-service

I have a service that sometimes needs to be running in the background. It needs to maintain a BT connection, so i cannot let the OS kill the service or else i'll lose the BT connection.

When i need the service to be foreground i call startForeground with the appropriate notification. All is working well except on some phones the OS still kills the service.

I read some of the other questions here and it all seems ok. This is the dump from sysdump:

```
Proc # 1: prcp  F/S/IF trm: 0 6566:com.testapp/u0a352 (fg-service)


* ServiceRecord{3d5bcd13 u0 com.testapp/.Services.TestService}

    intent={cmp=com.testapp/.Services.TestService}

    packageName=com.testapp

    processName=com.testapp

    baseDir=/data/app/com.testapp-1/base.apk

    dataDir=/data/data/com.testapp

    app=ProcessRecord{dce2526 6566:com.testapp/u0a352}

    isForeground=true foregroundId=12 foregroundNoti=Notification(pri=0 contentView=com.testapp/0x1090089 vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x62 color=0xff029789 originalPackageName=N originalUserId=0 vis=PRIVATE)

    createTime=-15m45s897ms startingBgTimeout=--

    lastActivity=-15m45s897ms restartTime=-15m45s897ms createdFromFg=true

    startRequested=true delayedStop=false stopIfKilled=false callStart=true lastStartId=1
```

How do the GPS running apps do it ? The OS won't kill the app during the run.

My app is similar to that.

Thanks

Comment: when does the OS kill your service?

Comment: The pattern (if it means anything) every 30m when batt high, random when batt low (as low as 5 minutes)

Comment: hmm, is that devise busy as hell?